# Ng Model is not working with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

This is my html

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="control-label col-md-12">Branch of Service</label>
        <div class="col-md-12"  ng-bind-html="branch_of_service" > </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-9" > </div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is Controller for angular JS

```
$scope.changeBranchOfService= function(element) {
    //console.log($(element).val());
    $scope.formData.applicationinfo.branch_of_service=$(element).val();

};
```

This is controller for PHP

```
$data['branch_of_service'] = 
getSelectCombo(
    $tblName = "cbx_branch_of_service",
    $cboxName = "branchOfService", 
    $optionValue = "branch_service_id", 
    $optionTxt = "value", 
    $classes = "form-control", 
    $id = 'branchOfService',
    $model='formData.applicationinfo.branch_of_service',
    $attributes = "onchange='angular.element(this).scope().changeBranchOfService(this)'",
    $selectedVal = ($guest['service_branch_id']) ? $guest['service_branch_id'] : set_value('service_branch_id'), 
    $whereCond = '', 
    $whereField = '', 
    $showDefaultSelectValue = "true"
);
```

Now neither ChangeBranchOfService function is calling nor NG-model is working i am new to angular 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you called `changeBranchOfService` this function?

Comment: it is called in js file for it,s controller, actually old developer has done this and he done this many places so i don't want to change it on many places i want its solution.

Comment: Try call using `formData.applicationinfo.branch_of_service` in `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: @Sai it is calling you can see $model='formData.applicationinfo.branch_of_service' in PHP controller

Comment: In that case your able to show that only when function is called. Otherwise @Sai variable is going to be undefined or have previous value

Comment: @Mr_Perfect even function is not called changeBranchOfService don't know why..

Comment: Yes, as @Mr_Perfect said you have to call function or use directly in `ng-bind-html` as I said.

Comment: But still you should use @Sai variable. Because it tries to find `branch_of_service` this in the scope. But you don't have that in the scope

Comment: i am calling this function $attributes = "onchange='angular.element(this).scope().changeBranchOfService(this)'",